# Как сделать запуск файла Python от имени администратора?

Tags: python, windows, права

Пытаюсь сделать сниффер пакетов. При выполнении получаю ошибку
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Попытался решить при помощи

```
import admin
if not admin.isUserAdmin():
        admin.runAsAdmin()
```

получаю ->
AttributeError: module 'admin' has no attribute 'isUserAdmin'
Как пофиксить?

Comment: Модуль [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672352/how-to-run-script-with-elevated-privilege-on-windows) брали?

Comment: Никак нет. Наткнулся на такой вариант решения, не помогло(

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить админ ли вы и при необходимости перезапустить скрипт с правами админа.

```py
import ctypes
import os
import sys


def is_admin():
    """Проверяем права"""
    try:
        # Если админ вернет True
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False


if is_admin():
    # Если админ продолжаем скрипт дальше
    input(" As Admin!!!\n Press Enter!")

else:
    # Перезапускаем скрипт с правами админа
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
        None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1
    )
    exit()  # выходим из старой версии скрипта

print("your code...")

# что-бы скрипт не закрылся мгновенно
os.system("pause")
```